# EF Core 6: How to use ILazyLoader (it doesn't get injected)

Tags: entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, iqueryable

I am trying to use ILazyLoader in my EF Core 6 application.

```cs
    public class IDM_Account
    {
        [Key]
        [StringLength(80)]
        public string account_id { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }


    public class IDM_Relation
    {
        public ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

        IDM_Account _account = null!;

        [ForeignKey("account_id")]
        public IDM_Account Account
        {
            get
            {
                if (LazyLoader != null)
                    LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _account);
                if (_account == null)
                    _account = new();
                return _account;
            }
            set => _account = value;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class idm_relationsController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly DS2DbContext _context;
        private readonly ILogger<idm_relationsController> _logger;

        public idm_relationsController(DS2DbContext context, 
                    ILogger<idm_relationsController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 15)]
        public IQueryable<IDM_Relation> Get()
        {
            return _context.idm_relations.Include(e => e.Account);
        }
    }
```

Btw, When forcing the load in the controller by getting a list from the IQueryable, all data is getting loaded:

```cs
    public IQueryable<IDM_Relation> Get()
    {
        var q = _context.idm_relations.Include(e => e.Account);
        var l = q.ToList();
        return q;
    }
```

The entire construct is used to return an IQueryable<IDM_Relation> retrieved from a table join in the related OData Controller.

When accessing the data records via the IQueryable returned, LazyLoader is always null. This does not line up with the info given in related posts on SO, as the IQueryable should be handled by EF Core 6, so as far as I have understood it a LazyLoader should have been injected into each data instance.

I am using an IQueryable<IDM_Relation> because I need to feed a data grid with an offset and a page size (record count). Imo lazy loading does exactly make sense here.

Comment: See my answer of the post marked as duplicate. Also the [official EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy). Note the `LazyLoader` **property**.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense to me and applying whatever I could get from it doesn't work for me. See my edited post. Furthermore, according to the post I was pointed to, the EF Core docs are wrong, so why do you think you need to point me to them?

Comment: I can reopen the question, no problem. But the `LazyLoader` property should work (tested). The link for docs was just to see their official example rather than other sources. Not sure why it doesn't work for you when it works for me, EF Core designers and other people. Anyway, question reopened, good luck.

Comment: Well, the Controller includes data of type IDM_Account from an idm_accounts table and returns an IQueryable<IDM_Relation>. When the grid walks through the IQueryable, looking at one IDM_Relation record after the other, none has LazyLoader set. I cannot tell why, since the data is coming from an EF Core 6 ODataController. I have added some more code to illustrate this.

Comment: OData might be the key. AFAIK it modifies the source queryable and uses projection (`Select`), so EF Core might not have a chance to inject lazy loader, create lazy loading or other proxy, or even `Include` related data.

Comment: Inclusion works - I tested it. It is also hard to believe that an OData Controller would mess up lazy loading, as lazy loading as far as I have understood is vital in many web based database queries (like e.g. filling a data grid), isn't it?

Comment: OData may produce `Select` - which removes Lazy loading completely. OData itself transforms `IQueryable` and feed EF Core with its own transformed query.

Comment: I resorted to a WebApiController, handling the inlinecount request there, and alas! it works. So I guess you guys are right, and on top of that returning query results from a table join doesn't seem to work with OData controllers either.

Comment: Ivan, could you please give me the link to the SO post you had linked here when you had closed my question for being a duplicate?

Comment: It seems to me that you actually need [auto-include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#model-configuration-for-auto-including-navigations).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to achieve what I was looking for is to pass $expand parameters to my OData controller.